# Whats the difference between git add -p and git add --patch?

Tags: git

Someone told me to use `git add --patch` but can't seem to distinguish the difference between that and `git add -p` that I used before.

- Whats the difference between git add -p and git add --patch ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference at all. `-p` is a shorthand for `--patch`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--p

> -p
>
> --patch
>
> Interactively choose hunks of patch between the index and the work tree and add them to the index. This gives the user a chance to review the difference before adding modified contents to the index.
>
> This effectively runs add --interactive, but bypasses the initial command menu and directly jumps to the patch subcommand. See “Interactive mode” for details.