# How do you commit a file without comments?

Tags: git, comments

I have a file that I am in the process of working on. I have some not-yet-ready features in commented code, while everything that is not in a comment works as expected.

Is it possible to commit a file *excluding* its comments? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I would not go though the trouble of commenting non-working code, and then removing it, instead I would commit everything to a separate branch, and then eventually when things works, possible rewrite the history, and finally merge/cherry-pick/rebase the changes into master/main.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to commit parts of a file?

Comment: @crea1 yes I guess so. I just want to exclude the comments. That said, I am all too conscious that I could be doing an xy problem here, so if there is a better solution then I'm all ears.

Comment: @JamesGeddes, you can use git add -i and choose the patch options, this way you can selected which part of the file you want to commit.

Answer (score 0):

Using `git add -p` (or the patch option from `git add -i`), as [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320498/how-do-you-commit-a-file-without-comments#comment126069519_71320498), is one way to do this.  See also [Commit only part of a file in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085162/1256452) and [Whats the difference between git add -p and git add --patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56017238/1256452).  Note that `git add -p` makes use of the fact that Git keeps, at all times, *three* copies of each "active" file.  Let's say your file is named `foo.py`, for concreteness:

- There's a version of `foo.py` in the *current commit*.  This copy *cannot be changed* because the files stored inside commits are permanent, read-only, and—for storage reasons among others—literally *shared* with any other matching copy of that file.  So if `foo.py` in this commit matches `foo.py` in any other commit, those commits literally share one copy of the file; changing it would affect both commits.  (More precisely, it would *break* both, as Git makes sure during file-extraction that the hash IDs all match up, and these wouldn't.)
- Meanwhile, there's another version of `foo.py` in Git's *index* AKA *staging area*.  This copy *can* be changed: it's in the compressed-and-de-duplicated format that Git uses in commits, but it is not in a commit, so it can just be deleted and a different pre-compressed-and-de-duplicated copy installed.
- Last, there's the version of `foo.py` you can open up in your editor or IDE or whatever, and work on / with.  This is the only one you can *see*, but Git won't actually use this one to make a new commit.

Git uses the index copy to make new commits.  So, `git add -p` will, in effect, extract the index copy, diff that against the working tree copy, and then let you add—or not add—any particular patch *to* the index copy.  The patching works by updating the temporary copy and `git add`-ing that temporary copy.<sup>1</sup>

Should you add something you don't want added, you can use `git reset -p`.  This works by diff-ing the index (proposed new commit) copy vs the frozen-for-all-time `foo.py` in the `HEAD` commit, allowing you to "un-add" individual hunks.  That is, `git add -p` incrementally takes the index copy towards the working tree copy, while `git reset -p` incrementally takes the index copy back towards the committed copy.

Sometimes, add and reset with `-p` are the way to go.  Sometimes though this is a lot of work, and you can make use of something else: Running `git add` on a file *copies* that file, *as it stands right now*, into Git's index (replacing the old copy that was in the index / staging-area).  So sometimes the way to handle this is to save the file in a temporary, run something—an editor, or a quick comment-stripping program you write, for instance—to weed out the stuff you don't want committed.  You can then `git add` *this* copy of `foo.py`.

In any case, when you think it is ready, run `git diff --staged -- foo.py` (or just `git diff --staged` or `git diff --cached`<sup>2</sup>) to observe the differences between the `HEAD` commit frozen-for-all-time copy, and the staged-for-commit index copy, of `foo.py` (or every file).  That shows you what changes you will commit if you run `git commit` right now.  Once that's the *right* set of changes, run `git commit` to make a new commit by freezing, for all time, the current contents of Git's index / staging-area.  This will become the new `HEAD` / current commit; `HEAD` and Git's index will now match.  Any working tree file differences are now "changes not staged for commit", including if you move a `foo.py.save-comments` version back at this point.

---

<sup>1</sup>The original `git add -p` code is a Perl script that literally does exactly this.  It is being, or has been, rewritten in C, but it still works the same internally.

<sup>2</sup>There is no difference at all between `git diff --cached` and `git diff --staged`.  Some commands take `--staged` only (`git restore`), some take `--cached` only (`git rm`), and some take either one (`git diff`).  This is not for any good reason; it's just a historical accident.  The term *staging area* for Git's index is the newest of the three: originally it was just the "cache" or the "index", depending on how it was being used and who wrote some bit of documentation.  The term *staging area* reflects how you use it, so is perhaps the best of the three terms, but it does miss out on some technical aspects of the index, so I tend to use the term "index".